# How to extract of sub-net of NetGraph correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

```
net = NetGraph[{3, 5, 8}, {1 -> 2 -> 3}, "Input" -> 2]
```

[image]

```
Take[net, {1, 2}]
```

[image]

But `net[[1 ;; 2]]` gives `Missing["NotPresent", {1 ;; 2}]`.

I find `net//Normal` is:

[image]

***But `{a, b, c}[[1 ;; 2]] == Take[{a, b, c}, {1, 2}]` returns `True`.***

And There is a more complicated net:

```
net = NetGraph[{EmbeddingLayer[32, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[0, 500]}]], 
          CatenateLayer[],64, Ramp, 43}, 
         {NetPort["EmbeddingLayerInput"] -> 1 -> 2, 
          NetPort["Input2"] -> 2, 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}, 
         "Input2" -> 12]
```

[image]

I want to extract the sub-net like this:

```
NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[], 64, Ramp, 43}, 
         {NetPort["Input"] -> 1, 
         NetPort["Input2"] -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4}, 
         "Input2" -> 12, "Input" -> 32]
```

[image]

The way I can figure out is use this:

```
NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[], Take[net, {3, NetPort@"Output"}]}, 
         {NetPort["Input"] -> 1, NetPort["Input2"] -> 1 -> 2}, 
         "Input2" -> 12, "Input" -> 32]
```

[image]

So how to extract of sub-net of `NetGraph` correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now, part syntax `[[]]` is mostly synonymous with `NetExtract`. NetExtract does not support slice syntax. For what it is worth, we are going to make an actual `NetTake` function at some point that is nice and clearly documented, I don't like using `Take` to hide this 'surgery' functionality, which doesn't work exactly like ordinary Take.

The second thing should be possible easily, but seems not to be at the moment owing to a bug with `CatenateLayer`, which cannot be constructed purely from graph inputs. Here are two ways you would do it once the bug is fixed:

```
Take[net, {{2, NetPort[1, "Output"]}, 5}]
VertexDelete[net, 1]
```